# Get difference between Window ShowDialog cancel and close

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, event-handling, caliburn.micro

In our app we use WPF and Caliburn Micro. We use a custom WindowManager:

```
public class OurWindowManager : Caliburn.Micro.WindowManager
{
    protected override Window EnsureWindow(object model, object view, bool isDialog)
    {
        var window = base.EnsureWindow(model, view, isDialog);
        if (isDialog) window.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
        window.Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/NWB.ico"));

        // TODO: Change to dynamic minWidth/minHeight based on window
        window.MinWidth = 600;

        new WindowSettingsBehavior().Attach(window);

        return window;
    }
}
```

In our code we mostly use this WindowManager like so:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    var result = _windowManager.ShowDialog(new ConfirmDialogViewModel("some title",
        "some text"));
    if(result == true){ // if OK is pressed
        // do something on OK
    }
    // do nothing
}
```

In one of my recent methods I want to do the following (in semi pseudo-code):

```
public void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    _windowManager.ShowDialog(new ConfirmDialogViewModel("some title", "some text"));
    //if window is closed without pressing any of the buttons
        return; // do nothing

    //if OK is pressed {
        // do something on OK
    }
    // if Cancel is pressed: do something else
}
```

Unfortunately, ShowDialog also returns false if the Window is closed (even though the ShowDialog returns a Nullable bool (`bool?`)).

So, what I did so far is just completely remove the Close Button by making a new `Window-Behavior`, and I've added it to the `OurWindowManager` class inside the `if(isDialog)`:

```
if (isDialog)
{
    window.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
    new WindowHideBarBehavior().Attach(window);
}
```

This works, and I now got a Window with just a title, and without a Close (X) button. Unfortunately, the window can still be closed with Alt+F4 and such. I thought about catching Alt+F4 and cancel the closing, but since Alt+F4 is standard Window behavior, I don't think users will appreciate it a lot and I find it a bit unintuitive for the users to disable it..

So, my question: How can I accomplish the pseudo-code in `SomeOtherMethod` mentioned above. Is there a way to get the difference between closing a Dialog or canceling a Dialog. (NOTE: As mentioned above, keep in mind we use `Caliburn.Micro.WindowManager`, not the default C# WPF one. Don't know if there are a lot of differences, but I guess there are at least some.)

---

EDIT:

I also know I can catch the closing event and cancel the closing:

```
window.Closing -= DisableDialogClosing;
if (isDialog)
{
    window.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
    new WindowHideBarBehavior().Attach(window);
    window.Closing += DisableDialogClosing;
}

...

private static void DisableDialogClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

But then it also cancels the closing when I want it to close (for example when the Cancel/OK button is pressed). Maybe I can add some kind of Property-flag to this overridden Closing-EventHandler, but perhaps you guys/girls have other suggestions to accomplish the same results.

Comment: I would consider the fact that it might be a bit unintuitive for the users if clicking cancel and closing the window do different things.

Comment: In winforms there was `CloseReason` passed as argument into `Form.Closing`, if there is not such (search?) in wpf, then you can implement it in your dialogs (as property).

Comment: @Sinatr As far as I know there is indeed no `CloseReason` in WPF. I've never worked with Forms myself, but I've indeed found some thing about it when Googling how to catch the difference between Cancel and Close.

Comment: Make enum, make property `ClosedBy`, if `Cancel` button were pressed set `ClosedBy = Cancel` and close window, (for `Ok` button - `ClosedBy = Ok`), default value can be `Unknown` (no idea how to distinguish `Alt-F4` from Windows closing request, but maybe you don't need it).

Comment: @BenRobinson Perhaps you're right.. Right now it is asking if the user want to save the data before continuing (yes, no and close should do nothing / cancel the action). Is it possible to call ShowDialog on a ViewModel with three buttons instead of two (so I have the same Dialog behavior as added in `OurWindowManager`)?

Comment: @Sinatr Thnx, easy to implement and it works. If you want you can add it as an answer so I can accept it, or should I add the answer myself of the result?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, I don't have solution to post. You can add own or accept Sheridan's answer (it's the same idea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [@Sinatr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1997232/sinatr)'s suggestion I've added a ClosedBy property to my ConfirmDialogViewModel:

(before):

```
public sealed class ConfirmDialogViewModel : Screen
{
    public ConfirmDialogViewModel(string title, string message)
    {
        DisplayName = title;
        Message = message;
    }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public void Ok()
    {
        TryClose(true);
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        TryClose(false);
    }
}
```

(after):

```
public sealed class ConfirmDialogViewModel : Screen
{
    public ClosedBy CloseReason { get; private set; }

    public ConfirmDialogViewModel(string title, string message)
    {
        DisplayName = title;
        Message = message;
        CloseReason = ClosedBy.Other;
    }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public void Ok()
    {
        CloseReason = ClosedBy.Ok;
        TryClose(true);
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        CloseReason = ClosedBy.Cancel;
        TryClose(false);
    }
}

public enum ClosedBy
{
    Other,
    Ok,
    Cancel
}
```

And I now use it like so:

```
public void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    var confirmDialog = new ConfirmDialogViewModel("some title", "some text");
    var result = _windowManager.ShowDialog(confirmDialog);
    if(result == null || confirmDialog.CloseReason == ClosedBy.Other) return;

    if(result == true && confirmDialog.CloseReason == ClosedBy.Ok){
        // Do something on OK
    }
    // Do something on cancel
}
```

I still kept the behavior to remove the close button, and also added `window.ShowInTaskbar = false;` to the `OurWindowManager` inside the `if(isDialog)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can fulfil your requirements if you just implement your own dialog `Window` by extending the `Window` class. From inside your custom `Window`, you can handle the `Closed` event and set the `Window.DialogResult` property to `null` in that case. For the normal `Ok` and `Cancel` states, you can simply attach `Click` handlers to those `Button`s and set the `Window.DialogResult` property to `true` and `false` accordingly.

```
private void CustomDialogWindow_Close(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = null;
}

private void OkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = true;
}

private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = false;
}
```

You could then check for the `Window` closed state like this:

```
if (CustomDialogWindow.DialogResult == null) DoSomethingUponDialogWindowClose();
```

You can find further helpful information in the following pages on MSDN:

> [Dialog Boxes Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx#Creating%5Fa%5FModal%5FCustom%5FDialog%5FBox)
>   [Window.DialogResult Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult.aspx)